# How to get PhoneGap 3.5 Android Hello World to work in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adt, cordova-3

I used PhoneGap 2.* without any problems, but now I cannot, for the life of me, get a basic “hello world” to work. I want to use the “platform-centered workflow” because my 2.* projects have a lot of customization.

Here’s what I’m doing:

I’nm on a Mac and have a folder ~/desktop/android with all my Eclipse projects.

Download https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/cordova-android-3.5.0.zip

Unzip it and put it in ~/desktop/android/cordova-android

Run /users/me/desktop/android/cordova-android/bin/create /users/me/desktop/android/hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

The project is successfully created!!!

As per the PhoneGap docs, I go to File > New Project > Android Project from Existing Code and select the “hello” directory.

I also check “copy projects into workspace” because it doesn’t work if unchecked.

There are actually two projects HelloWorld and HelloWorld-CordovaLib. I check them both.

If I try to run HelloWorld as an Android application, I get the following errors:
Config cannot be resolved
CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type (x3)
The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved
The method on Create(Bundle) of type HelloWorld must override or implement a supertype method

After looking over some previous questions, I decide to import cordova-android using File > Import > Existing Project into Workspace

Right click on the new Cordova folder in Eclipse and under Android make sure is Library is checked.

I clean and build everything.

I now get the error  “the project cannot be built until path errors are resolved”

What do I need to do to get a basic hello world PhoneGap 3.5 working???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was creating the project in the default Eclipse project directory. I created the project in a new directory:

/users/me/desktop/android/cordova-android/bin/create /users/me/desktop/mynewfolder/hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

Then in Eclipse, I did File > New Project > Android Project from Existing Code, check both projects but did NOT check copy projects into workspace.

Now I see that the HelloWorld-CordovaLib is green checked under libraries. After a few cleans and builds it all works.

As mentat said, I did not need to import the conrova-android project.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import cordova-android. Make sure you have a reference to HelloWorld-CordovaLib by right click on HelloWorld project, Properties -> Android -  Library list -> Add

It should have a green check for CordovaLib. Also try project -> clean the project, Eclipse needs it often.

Comment: I cannot add HelloWorld-CordovaLib as a library. When I first import the project it is in the library box but with a red X next to it. If I remove it and try to add, it doesn't appear in the list of projects. If I right click on HelloWorld-CordovaLib and select properties, it doesn't have Android on the left side menu.

Comment: Figured out that if I create the project in a different directory than my default eclipse folder, it works.